# Issues in Devise plugin. (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, devise, authentication

I have set up all things that the Devise needs. And things works fine for me.
But there is one thing very annoying:
  When I request the pages which need authentication through the browser(Firefox).It just pop out an alert dialog says:

---

```
"A username and password are being requested by http://localhost:3001. The site says: "Application"'
```

---

with the user name and password input fields instead of redirecting to the login page (the "/users/sign_in" page).But even, whatever user name and password I typed in, I just can't access (I can successfully login through the "/users/sign_in" with the same info).
Help please :(

---

Update with my model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

---

My controller (generated from the scaffold):

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_account!, :except => ['show', 'index']
  # GET /things
  # GET /things.xml
  def index
    @things = Thing.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @things }
    end
  end

  # GET /things/1
  # GET /things/1.xml
  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @thing }
    end
  end

  # GET /things/new
  # GET /things/new.xml
  def new
    @thing = Thing.new
....
```

---

if you need more information, please let me know  :)

Comment: it looks like you have enabled basic authentication. I don't know devise enough to give you a hint about how to disable it.

Comment: Thank you Augusto, almost solved the problem. I googled around but still find no perfect solutions, but find this: http://ewout.name/2010/04/http-basic-authentication-with-devise/ But new errors appear: " uninitialized constant Devise::Strategies::HttpAuthenticatable (NameError)"

Comment: Can you update the question with your user model? Do you use   devise :database_authenticatable?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a few weeks ago. I forget where I found this solution, but adding the following line to my devise initializer took care of the problem for me.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", :html]
```

Comment: Hi ezkl, I have added your lines to my devise.rb, but it seems nothing changes :(